# android progress bar not updating

Tags: android, progress

I can't update the progress bar.

I tried many solutions but it still didn't help so I think there's a problem i'm completely missing. I just added the entire code so you could better understand what I'm doing here. I'm fairly new so I'm focusing on making it work first and design later.

Here's my code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.adjust.sdk.Adjust;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private boolean doubleBackToExitPressedOnce;
    private int optimizedStatusNum = 0;
    private ProgressBar progress;
    private TextView barStatus;
    private String referrer1 = "referrer1";
    private String referrer2 = "referrer2";
    int delay = 100;
    int period = 2000;
    Intent notificationIntent;
    Context context;
    PendingIntent contentIntent;
    private static final int LIST_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION = 100;
    NotificationManager notificationManager;
    Notification pushNotifAd;


    @
    Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
        Handler handler = new Handler() {};
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                context = getApplicationContext();
                //checks the phone optimization process
                if (isAppInstalled(context, "com.qihoo.security")) {
                    optimizedStatusNum = 33 + optimizedStatusNum;
                }
                if (isAppInstalled(context, "com.lazyswipe")) {
                    optimizedStatusNum = 33 + optimizedStatusNum;
                }
                if (isAppInstalled(context, "com.apusapps.launcher")) {
                    optimizedStatusNum = 33 + optimizedStatusNum;
                }
                progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
                progress.setIndeterminate(false);
                progress.setProgress(0);
                barStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.barStatus);
                barStatus.setText("Phone speed: " + optimizedStatusNum + "%");

                //InstallReceiver myReceiver= new InstallReceiver();
                //myReceiver.onReceive(getApplicationContext(),getIntent());
                // referrer1=myReceiver.referrer1;

            }
        }, 2000);


        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            MainActivity.class);

        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Phone Optimizer");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
                R.drawable.ic_launcher));
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);

        addIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);

        pushNotif("3 Threats Found!", "Secure your phone now");



    }


    //shows a notif on user tray, just pass the title and text!
    public void pushNotif(String title, String text) {
        Context context = MainActivity.this
            .getApplicationContext();
        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        pushNotifAd = new Notification();
        pushNotifAd.icon = R.drawable.droid;
        pushNotifAd.tickerText = "3 Threats Found!";
        pushNotifAd.when = System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000000;


        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://link.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);

        notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);


        pushNotifAd.setLatestEventInfo(context, "3 threats found!",
            "Secure your phone now", contentIntent);

        notificationManager
            .notify(LIST_UPDATE_NOTIFICATION, pushNotifAd);


    }

    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Adjust.onResume(this);
    }
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Adjust.onPause();
    }

    public void apusBtn(View v) {
        progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        Adjust.trackEvent("yjno18");
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://link2.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public void secBtn(View v) {
        Adjust.trackEvent("yjno18");
        Toast.makeText(this, referrer1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://link3.com");
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);
    }


    /*
    this is how to call the isAppInstalled method:
    boolean sec360Found = isAppInstalled(getApplicationContext(), "com.qihoo.security");
    */

    public static boolean isAppInstalled(Context context, String packageName) {
        try {
            context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(packageName, 0);
            return true;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void lazyBtn(View v) {
        Adjust.trackEvent("yjno18");
        Toast.makeText(this, referrer2, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://link4.com");

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        startActivity(intent);


    }@
    Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }

        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Toast.makeText(this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @
            Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }


    @
    Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


}
```

my activity main xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:auto="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/awesomelayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            tools:context=".MainActivity">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iconimg"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"

                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />



            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar2"
                style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/SecMoreInfo"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                android:progress="1"
                android:max="100"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress_layout" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/barStatus"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/secdesc"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:textSize="23dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:textColor="#AEEEEE"
                android:text="Phone Speed: " />



            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/progressText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/progressBar2"
                android:textColor="#AEEEEE"
                android:textSize="23dp"
                android:text="Install Updates Now" />



        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>


    My drable/progress_layout file:

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

        <item
            android:id="@android:id/background"
            android:drawable="@drawable/progressimage"/>
        <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
            <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progressimage" />
        </item>

    </layer-list>
```

please let me know your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this helped me solve the bar update problem. Hope it will help you too

[progress bar not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348032/android-progressbar-does-not-update-progress-view-drawable)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html)  to see how you can update your ProgressBar properly from within a worker thread.
Inside the run() method **only** update your ProgressBar by `setProgress(mProgressStatus);`

The only code you have in your run() method is 
 `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` which is somewhat irrelevant as to what you want to achieve, while you have everything else outside the run() method. The properties of the ProgressBar are defined is the XML layout file so there is no need for you to `setMax()`.

Answer (score 0):

At first drawable/progress_layout like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/progressimage"/>
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progressimage" />
</item>
```

Then

```
    Handler handler = new Handler() {};
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            ProgressBar progress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
            progress.setIndeterminate(false);
            progress.setMax(100);
            progress.setProgress(20);
            progress.setMax(50);
            progress.setProgress(50);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    } , 2000);
```

There were syntax issues a lot

Comment: thank you! I tried it but still failed, crashed once switched to the main menu, still cluless on this one...

Comment: I don't know what is in the main_layout, I fixed that part, which is I see )

Comment: And ProgressBar you should put in the splash_screen.xml

Comment: thanks for the fast reply, I really do appreciate the help. You are right, so I added all the xml and java code. I hope that sheds some light on the problem.